# BCS entity code update

Tags: search, bcs

I have a problem with the develop with BCS and the Search in SharePoint 2013... I develop an entity that connect with UCM documents and it incorporates in search service (crawling, indexing, etc) 
The problem is when I have to update the code and the system takes the older DLL library... I have made an powhershell script that recreate the search content origin and stop the search service so I have the same issue.
someone can i help me, please?

Comment: I find the answer: updating the version of the Entity model... you can see this in [link](http://www.stum.de/2010/04/01/if-you-update-your-bcs-model-you-may-need-to-restart-the-osearch14-service/) Thank you